# Error 2762 when executing installer (WixCloseApplications) - worked with WiX 3.10.0.2103

Tags: wix, wix3

I have a problem with my installer that uses WiX.

I updated to WiX 3.10.3.3007 some time before and if I try to build an installer with VS 2015. I now get strange errors during the installation. The build itself works and doesn't show any errors.

The old installer, that was build with WiX 3.10.0.2103, still works as expected. I used the same sourcecode both times.

The installation log says this:

```
Action ended 12:19:13: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (58:F0) [12:19:13:127]: Doing action: RemoveExistingProducts
MSI (s) (58:F0) [12:19:13:127]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 12:19:13: RemoveExistingProducts.
MSI (s) (58:F0) [12:19:13:128]: Skipping RemoveExistingProducts action: current configuration is maintenance mode or an uninstall
Action ended 12:19:13: RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 0.
MSI (s) (58:F0) [12:19:13:129]: Doing action: WixCloseApplications
MSI (s) (58:F0) [12:19:13:129]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 12:19:13: WixCloseApplications.
MSI (s) (58:EC) [12:19:13:131]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI9A67.tmp, Entrypoint: WixCloseApplications
MSI (s) (58!B0) [12:19:13:137]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WixCloseApplicationsDeferred property. Its value is 'DisplayQ-Daily.exe3350002'.
MSI (s) (58!B0) [12:19:13:138]: Doing action: WixCloseApplicationsDeferred
MSI (s) (58!B0) [12:19:13:138]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 12:19:13: WixCloseApplicationsDeferred.
MSI (s) (58!B0) [12:19:13:139]: Note: 1: 2762 
MSI (s) (58!B0) [12:19:13:139]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (58!B0) [12:19:13:139]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2762 
DEBUG: Error 2762:  Unable to schedule operation. The action must be scheduled between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize.
MSI (c) (60:68) [12:19:13:146]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2762. The arguments are: , , 
MSI (s) (58!B0) [12:19:15:071]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (58!B0) [12:19:15:071]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (s) (58!B0) [12:19:15:071]: Product: DisplayQDaily -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2762. The arguments are: , , 

Action ended 12:19:15: WixCloseApplicationsDeferred. Return value 3.
WixCloseApplications:  Error 0x80070643: Failed MsiDoAction on deferred action
WixCloseApplications:  Error 0x80070643: failed to schedule WixCloseApplicationsDeferred action
CustomAction WixCloseApplications returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 12:19:15: WixCloseApplications. Return value 3.
```

I don't have defined the `WixCloseApplications` or `WixCloseApplicationsDeferred`.

Part of my `Product.wxs`:

```
<Product Id="*" Name="DDQD" Language="1033" Version="!(bind.fileVersion.Exe)" Manufacturer="HipHipHura" UpgradeCode="931619FF-BB02-475F-8853-D0623F3FF0CB">

    <Package InstallerVersion="405" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Installer" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="AutoGeneratedComponents"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="UninstallShortcutComponent"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CreateAppDataFolder" />
      <ComponentRef Id="Permission.AppDataFolder" />
    </Feature>

    <PropertyRef Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_452_OR_LATER_INSTALLED"/>
    <Condition Message=".NetFramework nicht installiert">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_452_OR_LATER_INSTALLED]]>
    </Condition>

    <Feature Id="VCRedist" Title="Visual C++ 13.0 Runtime" AllowAdvertise="no" Display="hidden" Level="1">
      <MergeRef Id="VCRedist"/>
    </Feature>

    <Component Id="CreateAppDataFolder" Directory="AppDataFolder" Guid="{78EDDF6C-110E-4020-97B8-5E55E3FFFA48}" KeyPath="yes">
      <CreateFolder />
    </Component>

    <Binary Id="CustomAction.CA.dll" SourceFile="..\CustomAction\bin\$(var.Configuration)\CustomAction.CA.dll" />
    <CustomAction Id="CloseApp" Return="check" Execute="immediate" BinaryKey="CustomAction.CA.dll" DllEntry="CloseApplicationAction" />

    <CustomAction Id="LaunchApp" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /C start myapp.exe --fromInstaller" Return="asyncNoWait" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="CloseApp" Before="LaunchConditions"/>
      <Custom Action="LaunchApp" OnExit="success">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <!--<util:CloseApplication Id="CloseApp" Target="myapp.exe"  RebootPrompt="no"   />/-->

  </Product>
```

It doesn't work whether or not I have the line `<util:CloseApplication Id="CloseApp" Target="myapp.exe"  RebootPrompt="no"   />` active.

I also tried to change the Ids and some other things... But had no luck. I tried to build the setup on different machines, but it didn't work also. And I tried it on a fresh Virtual Machine, where it worked...

Any idea why the installation fails on some machines and how I can fix this?

Comment: DEBUG: Error 2762:  Unable to schedule operation. The action must be scheduled between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize. Try scheduling CloseApp between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize

Comment: @BrianSutherland Yea - I tried this. But the failing action is not the CustomAction `CloseApp` and probably not the `CloseApplication` with the same Id but something different. I probably should add a different `Product.wxs` code I also tried... The one that is shown above is the one that worked with WiX 3.10.0

Comment: I assume you are trying to close an open application? The installer should do that automatically. If it can't, it will ask the user to reboot after the install.

Comment: @RobinJohnson - Yes, I want to close an open application that lives in the traybar (and which is always running (Autostart)). 

So the automatic closing doesn't work very well and I want to avoid the restart of the system.

Comment: If the application in the traybar depends on files in the install, the closeapp custom action would clearly need to be invoked before the installation process. As long as the closeapp depends on nothing actually in the install, you should be able to slot the action after FindRelatedProducts before CostInitialize. Convincing Wix to insert the action in the right place can be twicky.

Comment: If you have Orca - you can examine the msi and edit directly, then convince Wix to slot the action.

Answer (score 1):

The code with:

util:CloseApplication Id="CloseApp" Target="myapp.exe" RebootPrompt ="no"

is generally the right way to do it, depending on the options you want to use. That's the issue that needs analyzing, but it appears that you went ahead and tried to create your own custom action to call, and that's where you get the 2762 error from, which is as the log and Brian describe. All you need do is declare the element and let WiX do the rest. If that correct use of the element doesn't work (and what does that mean exactly?) then that's what needs debugging.

That failing custom action *is* associated with CloseApp. Internally, the custom action will try to close down the target app, but also will schedule a deferred custom action to make sure that app goes away. Because you're not using it in the documented way you're getting undefined results.

Also note that the log has a line "MSI (s) (58:F0) [12:19:13:128]: Skipping RemoveExistingProducts action: current configuration is maintenance mode or an uninstall". In other words you are NOT doing a fresh install of your MSI. The MSI product (as defined by its ProductCode) is already on the system. When you try to install the same MSI twice it does not install it again - it goes into maintenance mode for the currently installed product, so none of the changes you make to your MSI are relevant because it's always doing maintenance repair on the one that is already installed, complete with its erroneous custom action. You must uninstall that before trying your modified MSI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What I don't understand is, that even if I delete the `util:CloseApplication` line the setup fails on my develop machine while `Doing action: WixCloseApplications` (in the Log). Where does this action come from? I named my action `CloseApp` and the DllEntry is `CloseApplicationAction`. 

The setup works on other machines. Why does it fail on my developer machine?

BTW: I need a special handling for closing my running application. This "closing" works on other machines.

Comment: And the other thing I don't understand:

The error message says: "The action must be scheduled between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize." - I would say `CloseApp` is scheduled at the right point, am I wrong here?

Comment: You are getting undefined results because you're using it incorrectly. When it's broken it won't do what it should. The internal deferred custom action that I mentioned must be getting sequenced at the wrong point.

Comment: How is the correct way to use it? (It also fails if I upgrade the ProductCode).